# Why is there no blank space printed when there is a print() after an end function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("where is", end = ' ')
print()
print("Blank line")
```

Why is there no blank space between these two lines of code? From what I have, heard, the print() prints a blank line, so why does having print() after the end function cause there to be no blank space?

I am aware that the end function means that the end character is defined by the last whitespace and not a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` works just the way you think it does.
However, the preceding line has a print statement that does not end with a newline character; instead it prints a space.

So this what is printed:

```
where is<space><newline>Blank line'
```

- The <space> comes from the first print statement
- The <newline> comes from the second print statement
- You already know that `Blank line` comes from the third print statement

Answer (score 1):

`end = ' '` explicitly stops the first `print` from printing a newline. The output of the three statements is:

```
"where is " + "\n" + "Blank line\n"
```

i.e.

```
"where is \nBlank line\n"
```

Which results in:

```
where is 
Blank line
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `print()` function ends with a newline by default, however, the `print()` function has an option to modify that behavior. Using the `end = ' '` replaces the `\n` with a blank space.
[Python 3.9: Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
print("""where is

Blank line""")
```